# With PyMongo how do I import indexes using create_index() that were exported with index_information()?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

What do you need to do to the output of index_information() such that it can then be re-imported using create_index() or create_indexes() ?

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient("mongodb://host1")
>>> db = client.MYDB
>>> collection = db.MYCOLLECTION
>>> index = db.provisioning.index_information()
>>> index
{u'_id_': {u'ns': u'MYDB.MYCOLLECTION', u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 1}, u'Name_1': {u'unique': True, u'key': [(u'Name', 1)], u'v': 1, u'ns': u'MYDB.MYCOLLECTION', u'background': False}, u'MongoType_1': {u'key': [(u'MongoType', 1)], u'ns': u'MYDB.MYCOLLECTION', u'background': False, u'v': 1}}
>>> client2 = MongoClient("mongodb://host2")
>>> db2 = client2.MYDB
>>> collection2 = db2.MYCOLLECTION
>>> collection2.create_index(index)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1161, in create_index
    keys = helpers._index_list(keys)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 55, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
>>> collection2.create_indexes(index)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1046, in create_indexes
    raise TypeError("indexes must be a list")
TypeError: indexes must be a list
```

Comment: As per [Pymongo's documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=create_index#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) create_index or create_indexes methods requires a single key or list of key, direction pair. You can iterate over `index` in code and form a list which can be given to create_index method

Comment: How would that work?  Can you give me an example?

>>> for item in index.iteritems():
...     collection2.create_index(item)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1162, in create_index
    name = kwargs.setdefault("name", helpers._gen_index_name(keys))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 41, in _gen_index_name
    return _UUNDER.join(["%s_%s" % item for item in keys])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this basic code, this will iterate and add all index from one collection to other collection,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://host1")
db = client.MYDB
collection = db.MYCOLLECTION
index = db.provisioning.index_information()

client2 = MongoClient("mongodb://host2")
db2 = client2.MYDB
collection2 = db2.MYCOLLECTION
for i in index.keys():
    name_index = index[i]['key'][0][0]
    order = index[i]['key'][0][1]
    collection2.create_index([(name_index, order)])
```

Comment: What if your indexes are much more complicated, it doesnt appear it catches all of these:

        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "Thing1.Thing2" : 1,
                        "Thing1.Thing3" : 1,
                        "Thing1.Thing3" : 1,
                        "Thing1.Thing4" : 1
                },
                "unique" : true,
                "ns" : "MYDB.mycollection",
                "name" : "Thing1.Thing2_1_Thing1.Thing3_1_Thing1.Thing3_1_Thing1.Thing4_1"
        }